# Term for people who lack empathy, bikeshed, are overly idealistic, impractical

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests, idioms

This might be a long shot, but here goes.

I work in internet technology and often encounter (virtually and some times physically) people with the following characteristics. Is there a **term or phrase** that describes people with the following characteristics?

- highly critical of others' endeavors
- general lack of empathy
- overly idealistic (especially about technology)
- often engage in bikeshedding ([Parkinson's law of triviality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality))
- argumentative, often ranting
- fail to understand the average person's point of view

Any thoughts?

Comment: I find the term "people who do not agree with me" covers most of that. Perhaps you could provide more context on the situations in which these traits are displayed.

Comment: It happens a lot on internet forums, especially the discussion pages on Hacker News stories (news.ycombinator.com). I hardly ever engage with these people, so 'not agreeing with me' would not reflect what I'm looking for. I notice it more with their interactions with other people.

Comment: Oh, you mean Comic Book Guy? http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Jeffrey_Albertson

Comment: The particular combination of traits is considered the characteristic of a purported "rat race"; remember that they will, even if you they win, stay rats. So call them what you like.

Comment: Interesting question.  We do need a word for that label for that particular cluster of characteristics, so that we can start applying that label to one another in flamewars.

Comment: I think the main thing that triggers my brain to recognize this archetype is their lack of understanding of social context and inability to share enjoyment. @ choster haha, yeah that's pretty close. @ Pitarou good point.

Comment: I think this question is hopelessly Not Constructive. About the only common factor in these disparate characteristics is that OP has chosen to present them as negatives (they could have just as easily been presented positively - *candid, objective, pragmatic,* etc.). @Fortiter's *"people who do not agree with me"* is probably as good as it gets (but I'd go for the infinitely more expressive **assholes** myself! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting explanation of key traits of a sub-form of Antisocial Personality Disorder (ASPD) called *[Dissocial Personality Disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisocial_personality_disorder)*.

> > The World Health Organization's International Statistical Classification of Diseases and Related Health Problems, tenth edition
> >     (ICD-10), defines a conceptually similar disorder to antisocial
> >     personality disorder called (F60.2) Dissocial personality disorder. It
> >     is characterized by at least three of the following traits:
>
> 1. Callous unconcern for the feelings of others,
> 2. Gross and persistent attitude of irresponsibility and disregard for social norms, rules, and obligations,
> 3. Incapacity to maintain enduring relationships, though having no difficulty in establishing them,
> 4. Very low tolerance to frustration and a low threshold for discharge aggression, including violence;
> 5. Incapacity to experience guilt or to profit from experience, particularly punishment;
> 6. Markedly prone to blame others or to offer plausible rationalizations for the behavior that brought the person into
>      conflict with society

I can't imagine ever slinging, "You're a real DPD case" at someone in your office without sounding a little socially inept yourself, but it does validate the connection you see among those traits. With that said, I wouldn't hesitate to call a person who behaves in that manner and is bringing down the office (in decreasing levels of severity):

- abusive
- insolent
- scurrilous (if the person was also crude)
- a tech nazi
- A [Nick Burns](http://vimeo.com/24762900) (If your office watched SNL in the early 2000s)

Answer (score 1):

TBH that's just typical of many geeks. But, the hardcore examples can be "Evangelists" or "Fanbois" (Fanbois being blinkered evangelists for their chosen device, programming language, approach, idea, etc. to the exclusion of rational argument / criticism).

I'm sure there are plenty more terms on the [Hacker's Jargon Guide](http://catb.org/jargon/html/go01.html), although most are dated or US-specific. Weenie or wannabee might be suitably derogatory, if slightly obscure.

Comment: I think you're essentially right, the stereotypical geek or nerd fits the bill here.

Answer (score 0):

**narcissist** may be close: a person who is overly self-involved, and often vain and selfish, characterized by self-preoccupation, lack of empathy, and unconscious deficits in self-esteem.

Answer (score 0):

[apathetic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apathetic) pompous prick

[pompous prick](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pompous%20prick) is listed in urban dictionary

Answer (score -1):

Narcissistic personality disorder. Google it, read, compare the victims stories and experiences.  Odds are its what you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please include links and any references to support your answer.